# Path attribute in Spring

Tags: java, spring, class

Can anyone please explain how path attribute works in binding objects from a html form to a Java class in Spring. I am newbie to spring web framework please help.

Comment: Try searching "spring form tags". It looks like html tags with spring attributes to bind an html form to an object.

Comment: i did that but no useful information,was unable to understand,so tried asking Stack :)

Comment: see http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Long story short the path attribute is bound into java properties using java beans convention. For example for following form:

```
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="theStudent">
  Name: <form:input type="text" path="name"/>
  Cool?: <form:input type"checkbox" path="cool"/>
  <button>Save</button>
</form:form>
```

And following controller handler method:

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public String updateStudent(@ModelAttribute("theStudent") Student student) {
  // ...
}
```

Will bind automatically if the Student class is defined with following properties:

```
public class Student {
  private String name;
  public String getName() { return this.name; }
  public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

  private boolean cool;
  public boolean isCool() { return this.cool; }
  public void setCool(boolean cool) { this.cool = cool; }
}
```

More info of the JavaBeans convetion is available at [section 8.3 of the specification document](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javaee/spec-136004.html).

Comment: what about command object?

Comment: It's just another syntax for modelAttribute. So `commandObject="theStudent"` will give same result

Comment: Hello, this won't work unless you add commandName="command" in the form.